# Index.php Not Showing Up Properly In Facebook And Search Engines

Tags: php, html, css, facebook, search-engine

I have recently just designed a website and was forced to call out a small amount of code in PHP, which is located in the header, which forced me to rename the file index.php , and when I try to advertise it on Facebook, I get nothing, and I don't see much of it on Search Engines...

You can view the website here... http://www.thecommonwealthmembers.com/index.php

Thank you very much all,
Aaron Brewer

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to advertise it on Facebook, I get nothing"? You mean no title/description preview on FB?

Comment: You did notice that http://www.thecommonwealthmembers.com/ and http://www.thecommonwealthmembers.com/index.php show the same page? :)

Comment: @Damien: Yes, that is what I mean sir. @Goran: I do notice that Goran, I just wanted to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a brand-new domain, it can take a couple weeks to get into the search engines. A web spider isn't going to know it's a PHP page, so that shouldn't make a difference.

You might want to set the server to redirect the base domain to the "www" host, but that's a minor optimization. You should check out Google's [webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) which may help provide more info to get your site indexed a bit quicker.

**EDIT:**
rewrite example (if you do not use other hostnames besides www):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information provided. I am not hosting that website on a server, per se. But I am hosting is via a Web Hosting Provider, would I be able to make this change in cPanel? If so, how?

Comment: You can put a rewrite rule in your apache conf file or .htaccess file.

Comment: What is the coding for the rewrite rule. Thank you so much!

Comment: Added to answer for formatting. There are other ways to do it, but that should work for most apache environments. if you had other subdomains, you would change the line that has "!^www" to "!^(www|dev)" etc.

Comment: ldg: Thank you so much sir! I appreciate it very much so.

Answer (score 1):

i guess google hasn't yet index your website / domain name.

Comment: @froditus: Would you think that'd be the answer?

Comment: @froditus: I am guessing what the main of my question is... Does PHP files make HTML pages act differently in any major/minor ways?

Comment: @Aaron no, php makes perfectly good html, as long as you tell it to do so ;) I had a quick glance at your page and it looks good, if you're in doubt run it throug a validator. Still don't know about the issue, thou

Comment: @Damien: Thank you very much, I will run it through the W3C Validator. Thank you very much. :-D

Comment: i didn't really followed your question here. I thought your problem was abuout your web page doesn't showed up in google SE or facebook.

Comment: @froditus: No... It does not show up in Google Search Engine, yet. But mainly it does not show up properly when linked via Facebook (Status Update, Wall Post, Etc.) It doesn't give a link, a title, and or a description at all.

Comment: @Aaron Brewer, i didn't really followed your question here. I thought your problem was about your web page doesn't showed up in google SE or facebook. And for google, just like @lgd & @Damien described in their answer, it will take some time for google to index your page. I tried your link in facebook and your page link appear normaly. So what did i miss understood about your question ? :)